# How to set multiple values in NSDictionary with UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I want to save 10different values in one dictionary. 
With the same dictionary i want to fetch these all values in AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On UILocalNotification, there is a UserInfo Property.

When creating the notification, add these values with respective keys to the UserInfo Property.

Then in the App Delegate when handling the launch from the Notification, you can retrieve the values by using the keys on the UserInfo Property of the Local Notification.

[More Info on the UserInfo Property can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/userInfo)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `NSMutableDictionary`, with it you can add multiple key-values easily. And then you can set it in `userInfo` property of `UILocalNotification`.

Example of

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic setValue:someValue forKey:someUniqueKey];
[dic setObject:someValue forKey:someUniqueKey];
```